# How can I get the current datacontext from my control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a listbox that contains a control chooser I'm trying to develop.  Basically, the datasource is XML and I want to read the current context to decide which element control to display.

For this purpose I want to grab the XmlDataProvider with the current item's context, and evaluate that XML.  Within XAML I would write {Binding Path=@label} to retrieve a label attribute from the curretn XML element.  From code behind, I cant even figure where to get this XML, as it's passed to the class by the list control to this control, but not as an accessible property so far as I can find.

Anyway getting @label isn't sufficient; I want the XmlElement object in class ControlChooser, instantiated below.

```
 <ListBox 
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
  ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*[not(self::units)]}"
  >
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <W3V:ControlChooser/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <!-- Force the items to fill all available space. -->
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter 
        Property="VerticalContentAlignment" 
        Value="Stretch" 
        />
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Or, if you can suggest another way to get the job (switching what control is displayed) done....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found "[Different views / data template based on member variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190887/different-views-data-template-based-on-member-variable)" as the closest to an answer.  With the idea there, I could make a standalone control that made sense to me.  This is the key bit:

```
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding XPath=@kind}" Value="Number">
     <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SmallInt}" />
  </DataTrigger>
```

Here's the whole control:

```
<ContentControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:W3V="clr-namespace:W3.Views"
             x:Class="W3.Views.ControlChooser">
  <ContentControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="StringChoice" >
      <W3V:ComboView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="SmallInt" >
      <W3V:SpinView />
    </DataTemplate>

  </ContentControl.Resources>
  <ContentControl.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource StringChoice}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding XPath=@kind}" Value="Number">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SmallInt}" />
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple `DataTemplate`s to style the different element types.  If you are familiar with XSLT, `DataTemplate`s are the functional equivalent of `xsl:template`.

Example to style:

```
<Window x:Class="ZoomingScrollViewer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="testData" XPath="/Contacts/*">
            <x:XData>
                <Contacts xmlns="">
                    <Person Name="John" />
                    <Person Name="Robby" />
                    <Business>
                        <ContactName>Jemma</ContactName>
                        <BusinessName>Ars</BusinessName>
                    </Business>
                    <Business>
                        <BusinessName>The other one</BusinessName>
                    </Business>
                </Contacts>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource testData}}">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="Person">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@PersonName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="Business">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=ContactName}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=BusinessName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If you wanted to select the `DataTemplate` based off of an attribute, rather than an element, you can use a `DataTemplateSelector` to run arbitrary code as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301237/how-to-create-a-data-template-dependent-on-an-xml-attribute).

Comment: I think I shall need that DataTemplateSelector.  Thanks for the link.  (Or maybe I should tweak the XML data to have the right stuff.

Comment: Sure, if this solves your question, you can mark it as answered.